# Run .bashrc commands without opening a terminal

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I have been editing my `.bashrc` file to run some commands, such as appending directories to the `PATH` variable. However, from my knowledge, `.bashrc` is only executed when a terminal is opened. (Correct...?) In this case, in order to make the necessary changes to `PATH`, I would need to open up a terminal each time I log on to Ubuntu.

This doesn't seem like a very elegant thing to have to do, particularly for people who tend not to use the terminal much. Is there a way to run these commands when Ubuntu boots up, without requiring a terminal to be opened?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the `~/.profile` file gets loaded upon login. Just make your ajustment there.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the system/root run commands at boot if you adjust the `/etc/rc.local` file.

You should read over the [documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-customizing.en.html), but it's basically as simple as using `.bashrc`.  You'll want to make sure that all of the commands 'terminate', as to not hang your boot.

Example:

```
/path/to/some.sh
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, right-click the file in Nautilus and check the box `Allow executing file as program`. Then open up "Startup Applications" from the dash and click `Add`. Use `./.bashrc` as the command.

Comment: @Karnivaurus Did this answer your question?